# Authenticate user and admin separately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   protect_from_forgery

   skip_before_filter :authenticate_user! , :only => ["welcome#index"]

   # before_filter :authenticate_user! :except => ["welocme#index"]

   def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
      # user_dashboard_index_path
      user_dashboard_index_path
   end

   def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
      welcome_index_path
   end

   after_filter :authenticate_admin!

   def after_sign_in_path_for(admin)
      admin_dashboard_index_path
   end

   def after_sign_out_path_for(admin)
      welcome_index_path
   end

end
```

Admin should not access the users dashboard  and similarly user should not access the admin dashboard.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How did you setup your Devise ? Are you facing any roadblocks?  Devise wiki has info on how to achieve something like this. authenticate_* before_filters should help you to restrict access. If its not happening then please post relevant devise setup code also.

Answer (score 0):

i have done in my project:

```
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
if user_signed_in?
  user_dashboard_index_path
elsif admin_signed_in?
    admin_dashboard_index_path
else
   xyz_path
end
end
```

Same for sign-out:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
if user_signed_in?
   welcome_index_path
elsif admin_signed_in?
    welcome_index_path
else
    xyz_path
end
end
```

for authentication:

in (welcome/index)

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   contant_of user
<% else %>
   you are not authenticated #admin can not authenticate this page
 <% end %>
```

**Hope it would be helpfull**

Comment: it is throwing an error SyntaxError in WelcomeController#index

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

<% if user_signed_in? %>
   contant_of user
<% else %>
   you are not authenticated 
 <% end %>

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
if user_signed_in?
  user_dashboard_index_path
elsif admin_signed_in?
    admin_dashboard_index_path
else
    welcome_index_path
   end
   end

   def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
if user_signed_in?
   welcome_index_path
elsif admin_signed_in?
    welcome_index_path
else
    welcome_index_path
end
end /*is i am using correct code*/

Comment: are you using devise gem?

Comment: thank you code is working but after user login it is also accessing admin_dashboard/index and vice-versa

Comment: <% if admin_signed_in? %> #admin content <%else %> not authenticat <%end %>

Comment: what should be written in #admin content and not authenticat

Comment: The content which only admin can view, we can talk on skype or fb as you do not hav much reputation to chat on stack

Comment: white tshirt ? you can send me request on fb sneh pandya

Comment: what is u r skype username